# Split file into dictionary in one statement

Tags: python

I have a file that looks like

```
device1.dev:manf:up
device2.dev:manf:up
device3.dev:manf:up
device4.dev:manf:up
device5.dev:manf:down
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary holding the device name and status. At the minute my code looks like

```
        with open(r_file) as f:
            devices = (i.split(":")[0].split(".")[0] for i in f)
```

This gets me all the devices. I can also easily do

```
with open(r_file) as f:
            devices = (i.split(":")[2] for i in f)
```

to get the status, but

```
devices = {i.split(":")[0].split(".")[0] for i in f:i.split(":")[2] for i in f}
```

returns invalid syntax.

Is there a good way to do achieve a dictionary of

```
{device1:up, device2:up, device3:up, device4:up, device5:down}
```

that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me given your example data and desired results.

```
with open(r_file, 'r') as f:
    devices = {i.split('.', 1)[0]: i.rsplit(':', 1)[-1].strip() for i in f.readlines()}
```

Note that using `rsplit()` to get the status allows you to grab just the stuff you want from the right end of the string.  Also, I used `strip()` to remove the newlines.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say to use `re.split()` but keep it simple:

```
import re

with open(r_file) as source:
    devices = dict(re.split(r"\..*:", line.rstrip()) for line in source)

print(devices)
```

OUTPUT

```
% python3 test.py
{'device1': 'up', 'device2': 'up', 'device3': 'up', 'device4': 'up', 'device5': 'down'}
%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on multiple delimiters by replacing one delimiter with another before using Python's `str.split`:

```
with open(r_file) as f:
    devices = dict(i.rstrip().replace('.', ':').split(':')[::3] for i in f)
```

or you can use a regular expression (the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)):

```
with open(r_file) as f:
    devices = dict(re.match('(.*)\..*:(.*)', i).groups() for i in f)
```

Both return:

```
{'device1': 'up',
 'device2': 'up',
 'device3': 'up',
 'device4': 'up',
 'device5': 'down'}
```

Comment: Your first example needs to `*strip()` the data as it's producing output like, `{'device1': 'up\n', ...` for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution with `re.search()` function:

```
import re

with open(r_file) as f:
    pat = re.compile(r'^([^.]+).+?([^:]+)$')
    devices = dict(pat.search(r).groups() for r in f.read().splitlines())

print(devices)
```

The output:

```
{'device1': 'up', 'device2': 'up', 'device3': 'up', 'device4': 'up', 'device5': 'down'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re`:

```
import re
final_data = dict([re.sub('\.[a-zA-Z:]+:', ' ', i).split() for i in open('filename.txt')])
```

Output:

```
{'device5': 'down', 'device4': 'up', 'device1': 'up', 'device3': 'up', 'device2': 'up'}
```